# Webform GridView how can combine a row with same user but different data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I wanna know how can I combine a DataRow that the same user but include different data.
Now I got a table like this

```
User          extPhone_no_1        extPhone_no_2          extPhone_no_3
Mrs.Cheung        282                    null                   null
Mrs.Cheung        283                    null                   null
```

How can I make it becomes like this

```
User          extPhone_no_1        extPhone_no_2          extPhone_no_3
Mrs.Cheung        282,283                null                   null
```

Please help,Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("User");
    dt.Columns.Add("extPhone_no_1");
    dt.Columns.Add("extPhone_no_2");
    dt.Columns.Add("extPhone_no_3");

    dt.Rows.Add("Mrs.Cheung", "282", null, null);
    dt.Rows.Add("Mrs.Cheung", "283", null, null);

    dt.AcceptChanges();

    String strextPhone_no_1 = dt.AsEnumerable()
          .Select(row => row["extPhone_no_1"].ToString())
          .Aggregate((s1, s2) => String.Concat(s1, "," + s2));

    DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();

    dtNew.Columns.Add("User");
    dtNew.Columns.Add("extPhone_no_1");
    dtNew.Columns.Add("extPhone_no_2");
    dtNew.Columns.Add("extPhone_no_3");

    dtNew.Rows.Add("Mrs.Cheung", strextPhone_no_1, null, null);

dtNew.AcceptChanges();
```

Note:- First I have Created a Sample data.......with Name(dt) in DataTable 
then i again created a New DataTable with Name(dtNew)......with Comma Seprated Value

then you can bind the GridView.....

```
GridView1.DataSouce=dtNew;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

OutPut:-

[image]

I have Already Tested it...Posting an Image with Output...

Comment: It can achieve what I want, however it not really what i need.First my data is come from mssql, and there are more than one user in this query, so it will put all the user extphone no. in it

Comment: I use the SQL statement STUFF to slove my problem, Thank you akhilesh!

Comment: I think ....You want your solution from code behind ...that's I solved your problem code behind.....